# HTML form input moves when i add a border to the text box in CSS

Tags: html, css, forms

I would like to add a border to the input fields on my login form, however when i add border:1px solid black; to #login-form input then all of the text boxes move out of position.

Here is what it looks like without a border : https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0D3y.jpg

Here it is with the border : https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhnFo.jpg

When the user inputs the incorrect credentials into the form then a message is displayed above the form, this also causes the form to change position, this happens even when there is no border applied to the inputs.

Here is a screen shot of this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFIkQ.jpg

I have tried clearing all the floats however this did not make a difference:

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="sign_in_header">
        <div class="sign_in">Sign In</div><div class="sign_up">&nbsp;&nbsp;or&nbsp;<a href="register.php">Sign Up</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sign_in_text">
        Sign in with your account 
    </div>

<div id="login_error"></div>

<div id="login-form">
    <form method="post">
        <div id="login_form_input">
        <label>Email:</label><input align="right" text="Email" name="email" required />
        <br>
        <label>Password:</label><input type="password" name="pass" required />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="btn-login">Log In</button>
        <div class="sign_up_label"><a href="register.php">Not Registered ?</a></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.sign_in_header { 
    margin-top:40px;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom:1px solid #aaa;
    line-height:30px;
}
.sign_in, .sign_up{
    font-size:20px;
    color:#000000;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;  
    font-weight:300;
    display:inline-block;
}

.sign_up {
    font-size:14px;
}

.sign_up a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#0790cb;
}

.sign_up a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.sign_in_text {
    margin-top:20px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;  
    font-weight:500;
    font-size:16px;
}

#login-form { 
    margin-top:20px;
}

#login-form label {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:30px;

}

#login-form input {
    width:250px;
    height:25px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    clear:both;

}


#login-form button {
  -webkit-border-radius: 2;
  -moz-border-radius: 2;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border:none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;  
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #004d6e;
  padding: 8px 20px 8px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
    display:inline-block;

}

#login-form button:hover {
  background: #343434;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sign_up_label { 
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:20px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:300;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;  
}
```

If anybody would please be able to update my code with any solution and possibly explain how the issue was fixed - it would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: just a side note: why don't your labels target inputs, or wrap inputs??? they do nothing as is..

Answer (score 0):

I just increase margin bottom in `#login-form input` and add border in this.

```css
  margin-top:40px;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom:1px solid #aaa;
    line-height:30px;
}
.sign_in, .sign_up{
    font-size:20px;
    color:#000000;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;  
    font-weight:300;
    display:inline-block;
}

.sign_up {
    font-size:14px;
}

.sign_up a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#0790cb;
}

.sign_up a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.sign_in_text {
    margin-top:20px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;  
    font-weight:500;
    font-size:16px;
}

#login-form { 
    margin-top:20px;
}

#login-form label {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:30px;

}

#login-form input {
    width:250px;
    height:25px;
   border:1px solid black;
    margin-bottom:18px;/*increase margin -bottom*/
    clear:both;
 

}


#login-form button {
  -webkit-border-radius: 2;
  -moz-border-radius: 2;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border:none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;  
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #004d6e;
  padding: 8px 20px 8px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
    display:inline-block;

}

#login-form button:hover {
  background: #343434;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sign_up_label { 
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:20px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:300;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;  
}
```

```html
<div class="sign_in_header">
        <div class="sign_in">Sign In</div><div class="sign_up">&nbsp;&nbsp;or&nbsp;<a href="register.php">Sign Up</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sign_in_text">
        Sign in with your account 
    </div>

<div id="login_error"></div>

<div id="login-form">
    <form method="post">
        <div id="login_form_input">
        <label>Email:</label><input align="right" text="Email" name="email" required />
        <br>
        <label>Password:</label><input type="password" name="pass" required />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="btn-login">Log In</button>
        <div class="sign_up_label"><a href="register.php">Not Registered ?</a></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a second `<br>` after your fist input, it [works](http://jsfiddle.net/cgysbtpo/). Can't explain why your code wasn't working, thought.